# XCode crashing when constraint is deleted

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

I am working on adjusting constraints and other aspects of an app that was designed for iPod so that it will work on iPad. I am having an issue that for a few uilabels in storyboard when I try to delete some constraints Xcode crashes.

If I delete or uninstall the constraints in Regular x Regular mode xcode immediately crashes, if I do it in Any x Any mode xcode does not crash until I change to Regular x Regular mode, then it crashes.

It doesn't appear as if these constraints are needed in anyway and they do not conflict with anything, I edited what I could but with these constraints the app does not have a consistent look and feel throughout.

The constraints are very basic, the ones that crash every time I try to delete them are height on a couple labels (ex. height = 21)

Is there a solution for this? I have not been able to find answers online.

I am using xCode 7.3.1.

I found a similar question but no one answered: [Xcode crashing when deleting iPad RR variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635688/xcode-crashing-when-deleting-ipad-rr-variant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the newest version of Xcode, then try again and repost results. This sounds like a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately these apps are not currently compatible with the latest version of xcode and they have many users nationwide so updating is not an option at this point. While an update may help I want to point out that the person who asked the question that I linked to was using xcode 8.2.1 and was having similar issue.

Comment: I launched the app in xcode 8.3.1 to see what would happen and I was able to delete the constraint without crashing. It seems like this is some kind of bug in 7.3.1.